# Why does C++/CLI fail in runtime and not compile for non matching method

Tags: c++, c++-cli

I would like to know why my example below compiles, but fails when running? The class implementing the interface is a bit different. DoSomething implementation takes a const int, whereas in the interface it is just an int. Either the compiler should provide an error or the runtime should allow this, since I believe the const information can be ignored at runtime.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace System;

public interface class IFancyStuff
{
  void DoSomething(int x);
};

public ref class FancyClass : public IFancyStuff
{
public:
  virtual void DoSomething(const int x)
  {
    Console::WriteLine("hello world");  
  }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  IFancyStuff ^fc = gcnew FancyClass();
  fc->DoSomething(42);
  return 0;
}
```

This code compiles, but fails at runtime. Error when running this:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.TypeLoadException: Method 'DoSomething' in type 'FancyClass' from assembly 'CppCli, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.
   at wmain(Int32 argc, Char** argv)
   at _wmainCRTStartup()
```

/René

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem. Describe your problem in more detail or include a minimal example in the question itself.

Comment: It's better to write what is the specific behavior that you think is wrong and why so others might be able to help you (e.g How it fails? any error messages?)

Answer (score 0):

You have the inheritance the wrong way around.

Also you need to actually implement the specialized method to call the base method.

It should be

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace System;


public ref class FancyClass 
{
public:
  virtual void DoSomething(const int x)
  {
    Console::WriteLine("hello world");  
  }
};

public interface class IFancyStuff : public FancyClass
{
  void DoSomething(int x) {
      FancyClass::DoSomething( x );
   }

};


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  IFancyStuff ^fc = gcnew FancyClass();
  fc->DoSomething(42);
  return 0;
}
```